# align tooltipdialog top

Tags: javascript, dojo

i am using following code using dojo to have tooltipdialog ,, by using this code the dialog box is visible below the textbox , but i want to see on above to textbox ..

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
     <script language="JavaScript" src="dojo/dojoroot/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript">    
        </script>
         <script language="JavaScript" src="dojo/dojoroot/dijit/TooltipDialog.js" type="text/javascript" >    
        </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dojoroot/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />

        <script>
         dojo.require("dijit.TooltipDialog");

dojo.ready(function(){
    var myTooltipDialog = new dijit.TooltipDialog({
        id: 'myTooltipDialog',
        style: "width: 100px;",

        content: "<p>Nitin.",
        onMouseLeave: function(){
            dijit.popup.close(myTooltipDialog);
        }
    });

    dojo.connect(dojo.byId('thenode'), 'onmousedown', function(){ dijit.popup.open({popup: myTooltipDialog, around: dojo.byId('thenode')}) ;});
});
        </script>



    </head>
    <body class="claro">

<br/>
<br/>
 <input type="text" id="thenode"/>


    </body>
</html>
```

please give me some solution ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify 'orient' property in dijit.popup.open function's argument object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
<script src="./dojo-release-1.7.3-src/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dojo-release-1.7.3-src/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
<script>
  require([ "dojo/ready", "dijit/TooltipDialog" ], function(ready, TooltopDialog) {
    ready(function(){
      var myTooltipDialog = new TooltopDialog({
        id : 'myTooltipDialog',
        style : "width: 100px;",

        content : "<p>Nitin.</p>",
        onMouseLeave : function() {
          dijit.popup.close(myTooltipDialog);
        }
      });

      dojo.connect(dojo.byId('thenode'), 'onmousedown', function() {
        dijit.popup.open({
          popup : myTooltipDialog,
          around : dojo.byId('thenode'),
          orient: ['above']
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="thenode" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
</body>
</html>
```

dojo/dijit/popup.js:252 in Dojo 1.7.3 release.

```
orient = args.orient || ["below", "below-alt", "above", "above-alt"],
```